# mysql search and index performance

Tags: mysql, performance, search, indexing, normalization

Imagine you have a blog post that users can subscrive to comments
Is is faster to search on a table dedicated to manage subscriptions like:
ID, Post, User

or is it faster to have a field in the users table with their subcritions:
Subscriptions=|2|4|18|21|33|

or is it faster to have a field in the post table with the users that subscrive to that post:
Users_subscrive=|1|2|4|6|9|

Comment: Is the second suggestion a field with multiple values?

Comment: @Mike yes, sperated by | or , (comma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to have a **separate table** `Subscriptions`, with `ID`, `Post`, `User`.

(assuming `ID` the autoincrement PK of that table, Post a FK to a table `Posts`, `User` a FK to a table `Users`)

Both from a logical point of view (a subscription is its own entity, thus its own table) as for database performance, a separate table is the way to go.

This is a process called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), it will allow you to make joins, and perform complex queries, like "*Give me the last 5 users that have subscribed to this post*" or "*get all posts for this user which have changed since his last visit*".

It also **does not restrict you with a limit of maximum subscriptions** (where a fixed field in the users table always has a length).

It will allow you later to **easily extend your model**.  For example, different kinds of subscriptions: get notified by RSS, by mail, favorite posts...

Last but not least, since you are using MySQL, which is a relational database, this way of working (relations, get it?) is much faster in MySQL. It allows for **indexes** (quick search), **foreign keys** (users can't subscribe to a post that does not exist, if a post gets deleted, all subscriptions get **deleted automatically**) and much more.

Comment: You should read up on normalization, there are too many advantages to explain here. I will list some as examples, but the list is not exhaustive :)

Comment: And if you use a documment oriented DB NoSQL, like MongoDB ou CouchDB?

Comment: There you can "embed" tables. But it would be wise to read up a bit on relational vs non-relational systems before deciding which one to use - changing afterwards is harder than making the right decision at the start.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be faster to search actual table fields if they're properly indexed.

In fact it should be faster even if they're not indexed!